# How to covert a structure to a byte array in C?

Tags: c, struct, arrays

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to convert struct to char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433682/how-to-convert-struct-to-char-array-in-c)
>   [Portable way of writing a C struct to a file (Serialisation for C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274055/portable-way-of-writing-a-c-struct-to-a-file-serialisation-for-c)

I am looking for converting a structure to byte array in C and i was confused in doing that.Please show me a right way in achieving that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have a simple structure populated with integers, floats and one more struct inside, i need that structure to be converted in to a byte array which to be used in jni

Answer (score 1):

A structure is a byte array. it starts at `&mystruct` and has the length of `sizeof(mystruct_type)` bytes.

If the binaries are to long or do contain gaps, check the `#pragma pack` settings.

hth

Maro

Comment: Mario, can u give me an example of that